# Why does interval not matter for cdf of continuous random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

If $X$ is a continuous random variable then
$$F(b) - F(a) =  P(a  \leq  X  \leq  b) =   P(a  \lt  X  \leq  b) =  P(a  \leq  X  \lt  b) =  P(a  \lt  X  \lt  b)$$

Why does the equality not matter? And how will things change if $X$ wasn't continuous in interval $[a, b]$?

Answer (score 0):

Because by definition $P(X=c)=0$ for every $c\in\mathbb R$ when $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Observe for instance that consequently:
$$P(a\leq X\leq b)=P(X=a)+P(a<X\leq b)=0+P(a<X\leq b)=P(a<X\leq b)$$